# How do you restore console test when finished with the frambuffer?

Tags: c, linux, framebuffer, ioctl

I'm using ioctl to write to the Framebuffer, which is working very well.

However when I close it down the image is still on the screen.  I would like to restore the console text to how it was before I wrote to the buffer.
Anyone know how to do this?
The code below is what I am using;

```
  struct fb_var_screeninfo vinfo;


  fbfd = open("/dev/fb0", O_RDWR);
  if (!fbfd) {
    printf("Error: cannot open framebuffer device.\n");
    return(1);
  }

  // Get variable screen information
  if (ioctl(fbfd, FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO, &vinfo)) {
    printf("Error reading variable information.\n");
  }
  printf("Original %dx%d, %dbpp\n", vinfo.xres, vinfo.yres, 
         vinfo.bits_per_pixel );


  // map fb to user mem 
  screensize = finfo.smem_len;
  fbp = (char*)mmap(0, 
                screensize, 
                PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
                MAP_SHARED, 
                fbfd, 
                0);

  if ((int)fbp == -1) {
    printf("Failed to mmap.\n");
  }
  else {
// draw...some lines
    int x, y;
    unsigned int pix_offset;

    for (y = 0; y < (vinfo.yres / 2); y++) {
      for (x = 0; x < vinfo.xres; x++) {

        // calculate the pixel's byte offset inside the buffer
        // see the image above in the blog...
        pix_offset = x + y * finfo.line_length;

        // now this is about the same as fbp[pix_offset] = value
        *((char*)(fbp + pix_offset)) = 16 * x / vinfo.xres;

      }
    }

    sleep(5);
  }

  // cleanup
  munmap(fbp, screensize);
  if (ioctl(fbfd, FBIOPUT_VSCREENINFO, &orig_vinfo)) {
    printf("Error re-setting variable information.\n");
  }
  close(fbfd);

  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old, but I'm going to offer a solution to anybody who comes across this question (like I did).

What I usually do is to get a screen shot of the screen before writing to it with:

`cp /dev/fb0 /tmp/orig_screen`

When I'm done using the framebuffer I restore the previous screen with:

`cp /tmp/orig_screen /dev/fb0`